# Why those two different behaviors with WaitForSingleObject function in CPP

Tags: c++, windows

I have the following code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = { 0 };
    ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
    ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
    ShExecInfo.lpFile = "cmd.exe";
    ShExecInfo.lpParameters = "";
    ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
    ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
    ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;
    ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
    WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    std::cout << "hi! Im done!";
    system("pause");
}
```

When I try the code running `cmd.exe`, the message isn't printed to the screen until I closed the `cmd.exe` window.

However, when I try the code running `calc.exe` instead, the message is printed to the screen before the calculator process ends.

Why are these two executables exhibiting different behaviors?

I think I missed something with my understanding of the `WaitForSingleObject()` function.

Comment: You haven't initialized COM on the calling thread. You should not be expecting any particular outcome. Reading [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154.aspx) isn't optional. It also tells you about return values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried your code on Windows 10, and [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) shows the following:

[image]

As you can see, `calc.exe` spawns a new process and then ends, thus satisfying the wait. That is why you see your output immediately. This second process is the actual calculator process.  In my case, it is located at this path:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1612.3341.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Calculator.exe
```

Comment: This will be because Calculator is now a Store App.  (Sigh.)

Comment: right, now I understand why I could not start it from explorer

Answer (score 6):

As marcinj explained, `calc.exe` is launching a second process and then exiting immediately.  You are waiting on a `HANDLE` to the `calc.exe` process, so that wait is satisfied when `calc.exe` exits.

If you want to wait until all (grand)children processes have ended, you need to wrap the `calc.exe` process inside of a [Job object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161.aspx).

Call [`CreateJobObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682409.aspx), pass the `HANDLE` of the `calc.exe` process to [`AssignProcessToJobObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681949.aspx), and then wait for notifications from the job object (simply waiting on the job itself will not work, see [How do I wait until all processes in a job have exited?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130405-00/?p=4743) for an explanation why).

Any new processes that `calc.exe` launches, and that they launch, and so on, will automatically be added to the same job (unless they explicitly request not to be added to the job, via the `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB` flag of `CreateProcess()`, but let's not worry about that in this example).  When the job notifies you that all processes have ended, you can stop waiting for further notifications.

For example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HANDLE Job = CreateJobObject(NULL, NULL);
    if (!Job)
    {
        std::cout << "CreateJobObject, error " << GetLastError() << "\n";
        return 0;
    }

    HANDLE IOPort = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 1);
    if (!IOPort)
    {
        std::cout << "CreateIoCompletionPort, error " << GetLastError() << "\n";
        CloseHandle(Job);
        return 0;
    }

    JOBOBJECT_ASSOCIATE_COMPLETION_PORT Port;
    Port.CompletionKey = Job;
    Port.CompletionPort = IOPort;
    if (!SetInformationJobObject(Job, JobObjectAssociateCompletionPortInformation, &Port, sizeof(Port)))
    {
        std::cout << "SetInformation, error " << GetLastError() << "\n";
        CloseHandle(IOPort);
        CloseHandle(Job);
        return 0;
    }

    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};

    WCHAR cmdline[] = L"calc.exe";
    if (!CreateProcessW(NULL, cmdline, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        std::cout << "CreateProcess, error " << GetLastError() << "\n";
        CloseHandle(IOPort);
        CloseHandle(Job);
        return 0;
    }

    if (!AssignProcessToJobObject(Job, pi.hProcess))
    {
        std::cout << "Assign, error " << GetLastError() << "\n";
        TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(IOPort);
        CloseHandle(Job);
        return 0;
    }

    ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

    DWORD CompletionCode;
    ULONG_PTR CompletionKey;
    LPOVERLAPPED Overlapped;

    while (GetQueuedCompletionStatus(IOPort, &CompletionCode, &CompletionKey, &Overlapped, INFINITE))
    {
        if ((reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(CompletionKey) == Job) &&
            (CompletionCode == JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ACTIVE_PROCESS_ZERO))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(IOPort);
    CloseHandle(Job);

    std::cout << "hi! Im done!";

    return 0;
}
```